# MySQL- Last 6 months including current month

Tags: mysql, date, request, monthcalendar

I have this date format :
YYYY-MM-DD (example : 2022-05-10)
I want to extract only last 6 months inclunding current months.
The result normaly it's : june, july,august, september, octobre, november (6 last months)

I do this request :

```
Select created_date
from table_A
Where created_date >= now() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

The query gives me the last 7 months, that is to say from May 2022 to November 2022 and this is not what I want.

I want the last 6 months including the current month, i.e. from June to November

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Where created_date >= now() - INTERVAL 5 MONTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today is 2022-11-21 and you want everything on or after 2022-06-01?

That is beginning of current month (2022-11-01) - 5 months:

```
SELECT created_date
FROM table_A
WHERE created_date >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) - 1) DAY) - INTERVAL 5 MONTH;
```

Comment: ```WHERE created_date >= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')```

Comment: Your query may produce incorrect output. DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) may be not equal to those but 5 month before (for example, test for CURRENT_DATE = '2022-07-31').

Comment: @Akina of course, I did it the wrong way around. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @nnichols, thanks you for your answer. I want the dates from 2022-06-01 to today. That is to say the last 6 including the current month

Comment: @Juji - that is what this query will return.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is:

```
WHERE created_date >= last_day(current_date()) + interval 1 day - interval 6 month
```

Comment: Hi @ysth, thanks you for your answer, i test it and i will back